# Multiple data from UIActivityItemSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

Is there any way to provide multiple objects from a UIActivityItemSource?  For example, I would like to provide an NSString and UIImage to Mail, Facebook and Twitter so they are included in the same email/post/tweet.  I tried putting the objects in an NSArray and passing that, but it threw and exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out all I needed to do was provide multiple items to the activity controller, since each activity item source can only provide one item.